# react-bootstrap-table2 custom validator error message appears trimmed in the UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I wrote a cell validator according to [this example](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Cell%20Editing&selectedStory=Validation&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) (following is a shorter version of the original code):

```
{
    text: 'IPv4', 
    dataField: 'IPv4',
    validator: (newValue, row, column) => {
        if (!isValidIP(newValue)) {
            return {
                valid: false,
                message: 'Must be a valid IP address'
            };
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

The logic works well, but for some reason the error message is trimmed:

[image]

**Update:**

I inspected the html, and saw that when the validation method returns, the following component is added to the html file:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger in" role="alert">
    <strong>Must be a valid IP address</strong>
</div>
```

When I removed the 'alert' property from the class, the message appeared properly:

```
<div class="alert-danger in" role="alert">
    <strong>Must be a valid IP address</strong>
</div>
```

[image]

Any idea why does it happen and how can I programatically remove the alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turned out to be a css issue, due to the following css configurations:

```
.alert {
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Once I removed it the error message and the cell text were aligned.